# How can I disable the "Ding" in Win 7 when I use "copy"?

Tags: windows-7, audio, dell-latitude

Dell Latitude
Win 7

New computer (to me)

Whenever I highlight a word or phrase and copy it either via rt. click or ctrl-c, there is a loud, annoying "ding".

Edit: This happens in all applications. I followed the instructions in the tutorial listed below re: plug and play. When that made no difference, I returned the setting to system. Now the same ding happened when I used crtl-x. This is new. End edit.

I have searched the net for hours, turned off every sound scheme I can find in the control panel, tried following the instructions here: http://www.7tutorials.com/how-disable-system-beep-windows-7, all to no avail.

When I find do the "ding" or "beep" choice, no sound is selected. All sound schemes are set to off, all sounds found are off.

Does anyone know how I can turn this totally irritating sound off?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whenever you highlight a word or phrase in what? What's running at the time? Does it happen in Notepad? Internet Explorer? Word? At this point I suspect it's either a 'feature' of your mouse drivers (check for a control panel or system tray icon and look in there) or the program/app you're using when this happens.

Comment: Thank you Mark. It happens in all applications whenever I try to copy any text. I will edit my question to add the missing info. As I say in the question it also happens when I use ctrl-c. Also as I say in the question, I have disabled all "sound" options I can find in the control panel. As I typed this, the same "ding" happened when I used Ctrl-x as I cannot yet disable the track pad and the cursor jumps around. This is the first time ctrl-x has invoked the sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I went back into Control panel and reset sounds to "on". I rebooted and reset them back to "off".

That seems to have fixed the problem.